# parse xml file in php

Tags: php, xml

How to parse this type of files in php
I have tried using

```
<?php
$xml ="office.xml";

// get first book title
$title=$xml->featureMember->AA_OFFICE;
// show title
echo $title;
echo '<br/>';
?>
```

if iam using gml:featuremember instead of featuremember i am getting an error in syntax
if i use featuremember iam getting ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

```
<gml:boundedBy>
<gml:null>unknown</gml:null>
</gml:boundedBy>
<gml:featureMember>
<kgp:AA_OFFICE fid="AA_OFFICE.1">
<kgp:the_geom>
<gml:Point srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#32645">
<gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">643630.3815,2498825.0741</gml:coordinates>
</gml:Point>
</kgp:the_geom>
<kgp:Name>MANMARK EXPORT PVT LTD</kgp:Name>
<kgp:Type/>
<kgp:Plot_No>55</kgp:Plot_No>
<kgp:Block_Name>AA</kgp:Block_Name>
</kgp:AA_OFFICE>
</gml:featureMember>
```

Comment: you're doing it wrong, checkout SimpleXMLElement ...

Comment: Do you mean `$xml = simplexml_load_file("office.xml")`?

Comment: i have changed $xml ="office.xml"; to                               $xml = simplexml_load_file("office.xml")  But there is no change can u explain

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a string as an object. You have to create some form of XML Parsing object first. For example,

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("office.xml");
```

[More information](http://w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp)

or

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("office.xml");
```

[More information](http://w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp)

Comment: if I change $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("office.xml"); then i am getting Notice: Undefined property: DOMDocument::$featureMember  this error

Answer (score 0):

try to debug your xml

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml = simplexml_load_file("office.xml");
var_dump(libxml_get_errors());
```